# Draw a point on ESRI.ArcGIS.Mobile.WPF

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

I am using  ESRI.ArcGIS.Mobile.WPF dll to access the Map.

Using MapDoubleClick event is giving me X and Y coordinates. I need help in drawing a point on the Map based on X and Y coordinates I get from the doubleclick event.
I see that Map.Invalidate() must be used but ArcGis Mobile for WPF do not have Invalidate()